# hash code generation in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to generate hashcode for each row in my dataframe and need to append the hash code as a  new column "pitid" to dataframe.

i have tried below code but getting error

```
h=hashlib.md5(c)
```

here c is a dataframe.

error

```
TypeError: object supporting the buffer API required
```

Comment: concat all column into one using `concat_ws` and then use `md5` over it. It'll look something like `md5(concat_ws("," , df.columns.map(col(_) ) :_* ) )` in scala

Comment: can you please let me know the syntax in pyspark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below code in pyspark
here c is dataframe

```
h=c.rdd.map(lambda x: hash(x)) //generate hash code

r=Row("pitid")
h1=h.map(r).toDF() // converting rdd h to dataframe
```

to join two dataframes using monotonically_increasing_id

```
h2=h1.withColumn("rowId", monotonically_increasing_id())

c1=c.withColumn("rowId", monotonically_increasing_id())

c1.join(h2,c1.rowId==h2.rowId,'inner').drop(c1.rowId).drop(h2.rowId).show()
```

hope this works